# Reversing string using pop and push

Tags: java

Stack class may be the issue. My stack class is shown below.

```
public class Stack
{
    public static int maxSize; // size of stack array 
    public static char[] stackArray; 
    public static int top; // top of stack 


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Stack
     */
    public Stack(String str)
    {
        maxSize = 10; // set array size 
        stackArray = new char[maxSize]; // create array 
        top = -1; // no items yet

    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     * 
     * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
     * @return     the sum of x and y 
     */
    public static void push(char j)
    {
        top++;
        stackArray[top] = j; // increment top, insert item 
    }

    public static char pop()
    {
       return stackArray[top--]; //access item, decrement top
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (top == -1); 
    }
}
```

My main method is also shown below.

```
public static void main()
   {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = "";
        Stack stack = new Stack(str);

        System.out.println("Enter a string to be reversed: ");

        str = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
        }

        String strrev = "";
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){

            strrev += stack.pop(); 
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse of the string \"" + str + "\" is: \"" + strrev + "\"");
    }



       }
```

The problem is that everytime i run the program it doesnt output the reverse of hello, instead it outputs numbers 111108108101104. I think the pop() method is wrong

Comment: Why do you return long from `pop` method?

Comment: main() is not a class, it's a method.

Comment: Also, you do nothing with the `str` argument in your constructor.  That's not the source of your problems but it's weird.

Comment: As a side note, your Stack class is mixing instance/static in a way it shouldn't. You are treating `stack` as if it were an object but all of its members belong to the class. The object is empty and the only thing it does is reassign the (static!) fields in the constructor. Try instantiating a second Stack object and see what I mean. Here's the relevant tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stored char and then returned it converted to long. try `strrev += Character.toChars(stack.pop());`

Or, better modify your pop method, to return char.

```
public static char pop()
{
   return stackArray[top--]; //access item, decrement top
}
```

For string reversing you can use:

`new StringBuilder("Hello").reverse().toString()`

Use smth like [Commons.Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)  to more general solutions.

```
StringUtils.reverse()
ArrayUtils.reverse(char[] array)
```

Using of built-in or library methods is better. They are often well tested, and less buggy, than handwritten.

Comment: Thanks a million, That sorted it, don't know how i didn't notice that

Comment: @user3046825 Added some information about how such kind of tasks should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Changing pop as below will fix your issue. You should return a char instead of long.

```
public static char pop()
{
   return stackArray[top--]; //access item, decrement top
}
```

Comment: There is no charAt method for char array! You should use [] instead.

Comment: @Seagull, sorry I was distracted and assumed that it is a string for a moment. Fixed it.